How to add button inside action saw tooth in Odoo 17

I have a button in the first red frame, I want to put it in the saw wheel icon, how do I write js to do that?
I am in the treeview of model hr.employee.

You need to define an action menu item and add it to the cogMenu
Action Item
/** @odoo-module **/

import { Component } from "@odoo/owl";
import { DropdownItem } from "@web/core/dropdown/dropdown_item";
import { registry } from "@web/core/registry";
import { STATIC_ACTIONS_GROUP_NUMBER } from "@web/search/action_menus/action_menus";

const cogMenuRegistry = registry.category("cogMenu");

export class CustomAction extends Component {
    static template = "web.CustomAction";
    static components = { DropdownItem };

    async onClick() {
        
    }
}

export const CustomActionItem = {
   Component: CustomAction,
   groupNumber: STATIC_ACTIONS_GROUP_NUMBER,
   isDisplayed: async (env) =>
       env.config.viewType === "list" &&
       !env.model.root.selection.length && 
       env.searchModel.resModel === 'hr.employee'
};

cogMenuRegistry.add("custom-action-menu", CustomActionItem, { sequence: 19 });

Action template
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates xml:space="preserve">

    <t t-name="web.CustomAction">
        <DropdownItem class="'o_custom_action_menu'" onSelected.bind="onClick">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars me-1"/>Custom Action
        </DropdownItem>
    </t>

</templates>

Add the files the backend assets bundle
'assets': {
        'web.assets_backend': [
            'MODULE_NAME/static/src/components/*.js',
            'MODULE_NAME/static/src/components/*.xml',
        ],
    },


I still have a little trouble, I just want that button to only be in the tree view of the hr.employee model, now do it your way, no matter which tree view you are in, when you click on the cog action menu icon, there will be a button. there
@Kenly

You can add a condition and check the search model. Check my edit

i have list view with id = custom_hr_employee.tree_view_hr_employee_inherit.xml

I just want to display the list view with the id above, how do I do that?

Did you set the js_class attribute on the tree tag?

I wrote almost the same as you, adding:
env.model.root.resModel === "hr.employee"
But like this, it only responds to showing only in the hr.employee model, while with this model I will have many other tree views, so I want you to help me show it only in the treeview with id = custom_hr_employee.tree_view_hr_employee_inherit. xml

You can pass a variable ({'custom_action': True}) in the action context and use env.model.config.context.custom_action in the display condition. You need to provide more detail about the different views and models to provide a correct answer

I have this problem, hope if you have free time, you can take a look and help me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78495836/how-to-multiple-selection-options-with-owl-javascript-in-odoo-17

Can you help me with this problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78884827/how-to-domain-district-by-state-in-odoo-17

To add a custom button inside the action menu (chatter) of a form view in Odoo 17, you can follow these steps:

Define the Action:
First, ensure that you have defined an action in your model. For example:
<record id="action_my_model_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">My Model Form</field>
    <field name="res_model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="target">current</field>
</record>






    my.model.form.view
    hr.employee
    
        
            
                
            
            
                
            
        
    

Implement Button Action:
from odoo import models, api
class YourModel(models.Model):
_name = 'hr.employee'
@api.multi
def custom_button_action(self):
    # Perform desired actions here
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'hr.employee',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'target': 'current',
        'context': self.env.context,
    }

Apply Changes:
Update your Odoo module, refresh the interface, and navigate to the form view of your model
