How to multiple selection options with owl Javascript in Odoo 17
I want to be in a state where I will select more than 1 value at the same time, and when I'm done selecting, I can press x to delete it. I don't know much about owl javascript so I'm having difficulty.

Here is a search view code snippet:
<div class="col-6">
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <label for="status" class="col-form-label">Trạng thái</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <select class="form-select" id="status" name="status">
                            <option value="">-- Chọn trạng thái --</option>
                            <option value="draft">Dự thảo</option>
                            <option value="to_approve">Chờ phê duyệt</option>
                            <option value="approved">Đã phê duyệt</option>
                            <option value="cancel">Hủy</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>


You can use select2. Odoo uses version: 3.5.4

Can you write more clearly for me to see?
