How to domain district by state in Odoo 17?
In odoo, I have 2 fields: state_id and district_id. Essentially, I want to select a state, then when selecting a district, it will only show the districts that belong to that state. I usually do it like this:
t will create a dummy field
domain_district = fields.Char(compute='_compute_domain_district')

and calculate for that field, this field will store the id of the district school that you need to display
 @api.depends('state_id')
    def _compute_domain_district(self):
        for rec in self:
            if rec.state_id:
                districts = self.env['res.country.district'].sudo().search([('state_id', '=', rec.state_id.id)])
                domain = [('id', 'in', districts.ids)] if districts else []
            else:
                domain = []
            rec.domain_district = json.dumps(domain)

inside xml t just need
<field name="district_id" placeholder="District" domain="domain_district"
                               nolabel="1"/>

This method worked quite well, but I found it long and complicated because I had to create additional calculation fields, so I wanted a simpler approach than using the onchange function, I did the following:
 @api.onchange('state_id', 'district_id')
   def _onchange_state_id(self):
       result = {}
       if self.state_id:
           result['domain'] = {'district_id': [('state_id', '=', self.state_id.id)]}
       else:
           result['domain'] = {'district_id': [('id', 'in', [])]}
       return result

But this function doesn't seem to be correct, even though I've selected state_id, when selecting district_id, it doesn't filter out the correct records, it still shows all district_id, I need your help for the problem. This ?

This question is similar to: how to set domain with python in odoo. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I don't think this is the correct way to use @api.onchange in Odoo 17. When you modify fields on a form temporarily (i.e. the save/revert button appears at the top), the active record is duplicated into a temp record. @api.onchange can modify this temporary record when its dependencies are altered but it cannot affect the field's domain directly.
What you want to do is to modify the domain of district_id.
You can set a domain in the many2one field in your form view. If you defined the form view yourself, just add a domain to the <field name="district_id" domain=... />. Otherwise, if it is an already defined view, you would have to utilize xpath. If you google there are many guides explaining how to do so.
Alternatively, since you have an @api.onchange set up, I assume you inherited the model of the form you are trying to affect (if you didn't, please provide more of your code so that people can replicate/analyse the problem). If this is the case, you can simply copy the district_id = fields... definition from whichever model and add a domain to it. If you are not sure how to do it, look at any of the account models in the source code, it is used quite widely there.
If you do not want to overwrite any pre-defined domains in district_id, a last resort would be to define your own custom Many2One widget, if you can do Javascript. If you look at the "web" module, under "static/src/views/fields/many2one" there is a Many2OneField component you can extend. This component has a get domain() function that you can overwrite to change the domain that is passed into the Many2one field in the view. By default the returned domain is whatever domain has been defined in the Form or in the Model. By overwriting that function and making use of the Domain class in "web/core/domain", you can add on domains to it dynamically.

Please help me with this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78992875/how-can-i-set-all-form-fields-readonly-in-odoo-17-depending-on-a-field
